# google map not visible in ice cream sandwitch when we zoom out to highest level

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-maps

I have a Google Map application. When we zoom out to the highest level, the map
is not visible. Only some[image] grey lines are seen as shown in the figure. This happens only in ice cream sandwitch. This doesn't' happen in Froyo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because there isn't enough map information left to still fill the screen. You're at the point where the `MapView` would be showing the entire globe. You're getting the magnifying glasses with the (-) inside because the image data is not available for that zoom.

You have 1 of 2 options, 1, create a zoom checker... if the person zooms lower than (x) (5 or 4 would probably be a good zoomLevel), then reset the zoom level to (x). OR if you still need to show the entire world map, you can change your application to use landscape rather than portrait views. This same thing is happening with an application I'm developing, and I went with solution 1.